# How in Solr to distinguish during search between upper and low case characters in the results

Tags: solr

I have to search for words like ARM, Arm, and arm. Are 3 different words and when I search for example for ARM I should be able to see only the results for ARM and no for Arm and arm. 
I tried to apply a filter but seems not doing anything and want help to understand how to achieve this.
For example, I have to search also something like a "QSSTRESN" all uppercase and have to ignore the results if I type "qsstresn". So I will see results only for the all uppercase word.

I need a suggestion about how to do that.

I added in my schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.UpperCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CapitalizationFilterFactory" onlyFirstWord="true" keep="" keepIgnoreCase="true" okPrefix="QSSTRESN"/>

    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.UpperCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want case to matter, drop any lowercase or uppercase filters. These filters convert *all* characters to the same case, in effect negating any case sensitivity.

So the problem isn't that you're not applying the correct filter, it's that you're applying filters that remove the thing you're looking to keep.

Just:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

should be fine for what you want to do. If you also want to keep `A.B.C` as a single token (i.e. with punctuation), use a WhitespaceTokenizer instead.

The synonym expansion can still be present on query.

Comment: Ok, so instead of those filters I add only that. So when I search for a word like QSSTRESN should show only results for it but if I write the lower case will not show anything. That right?

Comment: Correct. Matching is case sensitive by default.